# Cython cannot convert Python object to 'Handle *'

Tags: python, cython

I am trying to wrap a cpp lib into `cython`. Here are some details:

`Handle.h`:

```
class Handle {
    public:
    // accessors
    // mutators  
};

class Store {
    public:
        Handle* lookup(char* handleName);
        int update(Handle*);
};
```

`handle.pyx`:

```
cdef extern from "Handle.h" namespace "xxx":
    cdef cppclass Handle:
        ....

cdef extern from "Handle.h" namespace "xxx":
    cdef cppclass Store:
        Handle* lookup(char*)
        int update(Handle*)

cdef class PyHandle:
    cdef Handle* handle
        ....

cdef class PyStore:
    cdef Store* store
    def __cinit__(self):
        store = ....
    def lookup(self, name):
        handle = self.store.lookup(name)
        pHandle = PyHandle()
        pHandle.handle = handle
        return pHandle
    def update(self, h):
        self.store.update(h.handle)
```

The last statement is giving me an error saying `Cannot convert Python object to 'Handle *'`. I know I am missing something simple. How do I pass the `Handle*` that is embedded in the Python object to the call?

Comment: The "h" passed to update(self, h) is a python object while store.update() takes Handle* as argument. That is what cython is saying. You should either convert python object to Handle* manually either make is cdef and type h parameter either make store.update() take python object as parameter.

Comment: How do we make the python object a Handle*? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly declare the parameter to Handle:

```
def update(self, Handle h):
        self.store.update(h.handle)
```

Comment: you might mean PyHandle instead of Handle